# Does Psalm 73:24 allude to eternal life?

Tags: genesis, psalms

Psalm 73:24
New International Version

> You guide me with your counsel, and afterward you will take me into glory.

What is the meaning of glory here?

Note the parallelism with
Genesis 5:24

> Enoch walked with God, and then he was no more, because God had taken him away.

Answer (score 3):

Verses 25 and 26 provide the answer you seek:

> Whom have I in heaven but you?  And earth has nothing I desire besides you.

> My flesh and my heart may fail, but God is the strength of my heart and my portion for ever.

The preceding verses help to put this Psalm into context.  The arrogant and the wicked, who appear to be healthy and strong and who seem to prosper, will be cast down to ruin and destroyed by God.  Their final destiny is not that of the man whose refuge is the Sovereign Lord (verses 27-28).

The psalmist had his eyes fixed on the promises of God. In faith, he looked forward to being forever in His holy presence.

EDIT:Forgive me for failing to address Genesis 5:24 where God "had taken [Enoch] away". Enoch did not experience death which is an exception to the rule.  Psalm 49:15 expresses the view that "God will redeem my life from the grave". From there, the Old Testament saints who walked by faith, had an expectation of life after the death of the phyical body.

> Instead, they were longing for a better country, a heavenly one (Hebrews 11:16)

That is the ultimate destination of all who walk with God in faith.

Comment: Great answer - simple and explicit. +1.

Comment: Lesley:In view of Jesus’ clear statement at John 3:13. Enoch was not taken to heaven. It appears that, as in the case of Moses’ body, God disposed of Enoch’s body, for "he was nowhere to be found."  Deuter. 34:5, 6; Jude 9.

Comment: In light of Jesus’ comment, ‘no one has ascended to heaven’, to be in heaven is more a state of being and life than a place. God doesn’t need a place to be, He just is, He chooses to draw us to Himself, through His son.

Answer (score 1):

**Does Psalm 73:24 allude to eternal life?**

**What is the meaning of glory here?**

Asaph the Psalmist felt that the wicked were better off than the righteous [Psalm 73:2-12]. Allowing God's counsel to lead him resulted in his receiving "glory" that is favor with God, a close relationship with him. In Psalm 73:28 he wrote.

Psalm 73:28 NASB

> 28 But as for me, the nearness of God is good for me;  I have made the
> Lord [a]God my refuge,  So that I may tell of all Your works.

**Does **Psalm 73:24 allude to eternal life?  Yes ,on the earth. Read notes below.****

For all those that hope in  God and keep his ways are promised:  That He [God]will exalt them to take possession of the earth. When the wicked ones are cut off,  (Ps. 37:34) they look forward to experiencing beyond compare the honor of receiving everlasting life on earth..​(Ps. 37:29. Mt 5:5 )

Psalm 37:34   Aramaic Bible in Plain English

> Hope in Lord Jehovah and keep his way, and he will exalt you to
> inherit the Earth; when the wicked are destroyed, you will see it.

Psalm 37:29Aramaic Bible in Plain English

> And the righteous ones inherit the Earth and dwell upon it for
> eternity.

Matthew 5:5 NASB

**5 “Blessed are the [c]gentle, for they will inherit the earth.**

**Notes:**

There is nothing in the Scriptures to show that a heavenly hope was held out to God’s servants prior to the coming of Christ Jesus. Such hope first appears in Jesus’ expressions to his disciples (Mt 19:21, 23-28; Lu 12:32; Joh 14:2, 3) and was fully comprehended by them only after Pentecost of 33 C.E.​—Ac 1:6-8; 2:1-4, 29-36; Ro 8:16, 17.